# How to include Index Match function in VBA to return output when two inputs are found on output sheet

Tags: excel, vba, match

I have used Index match functionality to return a value based on two inputs on an excel sheet, but I cannot get it to work in a VBA macro at the moment.

Basically I have two input columns on Sheet1 and two matching columns on Sheet2, and then an output on Sheet2 based upon the two input values matching somewhere on their sister columns on Sheet2.

When input into a cell on the worksheet, it returns the correct result. See below.
`=INDEX('Sheet1'!L:L,MATCH(1,('Sheet2'!F2='Sheet1'!D:D)*('Sheet2'!J2='Sheet1'!J:J),0))`

For the record, I did achieve my intended result with a nested for loop, but the run times were abysmal, I figured this might speed things up.

I've tested to make sure the ranges are all set up correctly, and the variables are not empty, yet I get the error '13' Type mismatch.

```
Sheet2.Cells(rowvvar, outputcol).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.index(OutputRange, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(1, (Input1  = InputRange1) * (Input2 = InputRange2),0))
```

Comment: Use `Worksheet.Evaluate` here, passing it your formula as a `String`: `Sheet2.Cells(rowvvar, outputcol).Value = Sheet2.Evaluate("=INDEX('Sheet1'!L:L,MATCH(1,('Sheet2'!F2='Sheet1'!D:D)*('Sheet2'!J2='Sheet1'!J:J),0))")`

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you for your response.
That code ran with no errors! So we are getting there.
However, it ran the code only searching for the first set of data on row 2 (F2, J2). 
Is there a way to incorporate a For loop to run through the rowvar # to change the row numbers as it runs?

Comment: Ah. `Sheet2.Cells(rowvvar, outputcol).Value = Sheet2.Evaluate("=INDEX('Sheet1'!L:L,MATCH(1,('Sheet2'!F" & rowvvar & "='Sheet1'!D:D)*('Sheet2'!J" & rowvvar & "='Sheet1'!J:J),0))")`

Comment: I saw this was closed, so I'm not sure if I can ask another question but it's worth a shot.
This has been amazingly helpful, but I am curious if I can set the Sheet names as variable code names based on the sheets that a user would input? for instance, when the code I have initially runs, it has a user pull in the "sheet2", and "sheet1" is the initial. I have codenames set up for both within VBA, is there a way to input, say, "ws2" in lieu of 'sheet2' ? Or no because it's an excel worksheet application?

Comment: Something like: `Dim ws2 As Worksheet`, `Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")`? Or `Dim s As String`, `s = "Sheet2"`, then `Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(s)`?

Comment: Got it! Just needed to add some extra ampersands and apostrophes. & "'" s & "'" & !J etc.
Thank you again!

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood your comment, and was thinking of the `Worksheet` variable instead of the formula you were writing. Yep, apostrophes around the sheet name and `&` to concatenate.